# Solving with the Derivative

Tags: calculus

$$f(x)=\sqrt{x+4\sin(x)}$$

Would the derivative be: $1/2(1+\sin(x)+4\cos(x)$

If that's correct, how would I solve, setting it equal to zero?

Answer (score 4):

By the chain rule, we get:

$$f'(x) = \frac 12(x + 4\sin x)^{-1/2} \cdot (1 + 4\cos x) = \dfrac{1+4\cos x}{2 \sqrt{x + 4\sin x}}$$

To solve $f'(x) = 0$, note that $$f'(x) = 0 \iff 1+4\cos x = 0 \iff \cos x = -\dfrac{1}{4}$$

Comment: How would you solve for the second derivative

Comment: Use the quotient rule, or else express the denominator as $\frac 12(x + 4\sin x)^{-1/2}$ and use the product rule. You will invariably need to use the chain rule again!